# GoogleApiException with statuscode NotFound when updating OrganisationUnits using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory service

Tags: .net, google-apps-for-education

I am trying to update an OrganisationUnit using the following code

> OrgunitsResource.ListRequest orgUnitListRequest =
>   googleAppsOAuthService.Orgunits.List(superadmin.customerId);
>   orgUnitListRequest.Type = OrgunitsResource.ListRequest.TypeEnum.All;
>   orgUnitListRequest.OrgUnitPath = orgUnitName; OrgUnits unitsResult =
>   orgUnitListRequest.Execute(); List orgUnitResults =
>   unitsResult.OrganizationUnits.ToList(); OrgUnit unit = new OrgUnit();
>   unit.Description = "some description"; unit.ParentOrgUnitPath
>   =unitsResult.OrganizationUnits[2].ParentOrgUnitPath; unit.Name = unitsResult.OrganizationUnits[2].Name; // updating orgunit
>   List list = new List(); list.Add(unit.Name);
>   googleAppsOAuthService.Orgunits.Update(unit, superadmin.customerId,
>   list).Execute();

But it throws me a GoogleApiException with the statuscode.NotFound? Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the list parameter in "googleAppsOAuthService.Orgunits.Update(unit, superadmin.customerId, **list**).Execute();"

The **list** was having the orgUnitName. Instead I should have used the OrgUnitPath. OrgUnitPath should be in the format "AllEstablishmentUsers/Students". **Note that there should be no preceeding "/" for the OUs directly coming under the deafult Organisation Unit** (that is the AllEstablishmentUsers in the above example should not be preceeded by a "/") when you are specifying the OrgUnitPath to get/list/update Organisation Unit(s) using google apps Oauth admin directory for .net.